# Rails devise set authorisation on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a standard devise implementation and throughout other models there seems to be no redirect if the session is expired, leaving the user with a error message.

For example on the user profile page if not logged in it will just show an error because the current_user does not exist.

Do i set in each model stating to authorise. Or a better solution, can I set it in the app controller and do it application wide and simply set any public pages wherever necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular controller to check if a user is logged in then you want to use Devise's authenticate_user! function.  See example below

```
class StuffController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    ..... more implementation
  end
end
```

If the user is not logged in they will be redirected to the login form and then to the required page after a successful login

Answer (score 0):

Use a before filter such as `before_filter :authenticate_user!`. Place this in your application controller. `authenticate_user!` is a devise helper so if you want custom behavior you can overload the method or simply write your own filter using their `user_signed_in?` helper method.